# What could be a snappy equivalent for the French catchphrase "si c'est gratuit vous êtes le produit"?

Tags: french, phrase-requests

"Si c'est gratuit vous êtes le produit" can be translated literally as "If it's free then you are the product".

It expresses the idea that if something is free (like Facebook) then the information you are outputting is being used commercially.

Can you think of a way to transcribe this into the English language?

[image]

Comment: I've seen versions of that in English for years; Google your sentence without quotes and choose whichever flavor you like best.

Comment: The French really doesn't make sense. It just rhymes. Because if it's free, you aren't the product, you are the potential customer for the next time round.

Comment: @Lambie: I think the idea here is that, if you can get something free by filling out a registration form that includes various bits of demographic information about you, the service or site or whatever that is offering its content to you for free may actually be selling that information to advertisers and others for whom you are a target; in that sense, your personal data ("you") is a product.

Comment: I disagree, @Lambie. In the case of Facebook, it is clear that we users _are_ the product being sold to the (paying) customers.

Comment: Interesting; I come from a multilingual background (including English and French) and definitely think of this as an English saying, was it really French originally?

Comment: @KWinker - Perfectly demonstrating the underlying point by using "Google" as a verb.  Think about how much processing power and bandwidth goes into every single search query.  Ever wonder why Google doesn't charge you for use of their technology?  Yup.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

How about,

***if you don't pay you're giving yourself away.***

Comment: Upvoted because it rhymes

Comment: Shorter: _If you don't pay, you give yourself away_. This improves the rhythm, the part lengths are now more balanced.

Comment: @MSalters - nice! (although, as a song writer, I find it can be helpful to have lyrics with a certain awkward asymmetry).

Comment: how 'bout *you sell yourself away, @MSalters ? sounds even more catchy.

Comment: Excellen! If Prof Yaffle's answer is the most complete I'll accept this answer for the effort put in for both a concise form and the rhyme :)

Answer (score 21):

There are many variations, all of which roughly translate to the same as the French you quote. There's no "definitive" version.

A quick Google produces examples including:

> If you are not paying for it, you're not the customer; you're the product being sold

https://www.quora.com/Who-originally-suggested-that-if-youre-not-paying-for-the-product-you-are-the-product

> If You're Not Paying For It, You Become The Product

http://www.forbes.com/sites/marketshare/2012/03/05/if-youre-not-paying-for-it-you-become-the-product/#7591707eb445

> If You're Not Paying for It; You're the Product

http://lifehacker.com/5697167/if-youre-not-paying-for-it-youre-the-product

... so you'd be fine to use "if it's free then you're the product" if that's what you want.

Comment: _You're not the customer; you're the product_

Comment: A nice image that tells the same story can be found at http://geek-and-poke.com/geekandpoke/2010/12/21/the-free-model.html (disclaimer: nothing to do with me, I just like it).

Comment: Thanks Prof Yaffle. Would have accepted this answer but Dan as a song writer seems to have found the best equivalent in both meaning and form.

Comment: @JamesPoulson - I think Dan's rhyming form is a less literal translation, more in the spirit of the French version. I'll accept that!

Answer (score 11):

If you're not paying for a product, you *are* the product.

Answer (score 9):

Try [there's no such thing as a free lunch](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/there-s-no-such-thing-as-a-free-lunch_2).

> It is used for saying that people cannot get something good, especially for free, without working hard or giving something in exchange.

Comment: I think it lacks the "you become the product" part.

Comment: @Josh61 I believe if I am getting something good for free (like Facebook mentioned by the op), then I must have already, to my knowledge or not, sacrificed or paid for it in some way. This "sacrifice or payment" is becoming a product, in this case me, that advertises the name of Facebook among my friends and family. People saying that I use Facebook all the time, have it on everything with a screen on it and stuff like that just corroborates the fact that I am a product. What do you think?

Comment: Usual rendering of " there's no such thing as a free lunch" in French are *tout se paie* or *rien n'est gratuit* or *on n'a rien sans rien".

Answer (score 9):

A frequently used adage in the UK is:

***If the deal you are being offered seems too good to be true, it probably is***.

Comment: This seems like a related but not identical quote – the OP's one is saying that if you don't pay for something with money, you pay with something else, like attention or time; yours is that offers which seem to be perfect are likely scams or lies, at least from how it's used here.

Comment: In American it's just: *If it's too good to be true, it probably is.* [Hotlicks](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/70861/hot-licks) prob has the T-shirt.

Comment: @Mazura It probably is here, too. I only wrote the longer version to aid comprehension.

Answer (score 6):

Would this work?

> "If it's free, they're selling you."

---

**EDIT: Adding my explanation from the comments, as requested.**

I was reaching for something concise, while maintaining an acerbic tone. Since the original described "you" as being the product, the intent in saying "they're selling you" was to reduce the individual to a commodity - no different than "they're selling cars."

Comment: I didn’t even understand this the first time I read it.  *Selling* generally isn’t directly associated with people; when it is, it’s in connection with slavery.  When ***sell*** is followed by a word or name for a person, that person is usually an *indirect object*; e.g., I could sell you my car.  When I read “they’re selling you,” I thought “That sentence is missing a direct object — *what* are they selling me?”

Comment: Would it loose the confusion @Scott talks about if the sentence was rearranged to say: *"If it's free, it's you they're selling."?

Comment: @neil: I guess that would be better.  I would say "it's you ***that*** they're selling," but I'm a little pedantic about that.

Comment: I was reaching for something concise, while maintaining an acerbic tone. Since the original described "you" as being the product, the intent in saying "they're selling you" was to reduce the individual to a commodity - no different than "they're selling cars." However, I can definitely see the confusion when reading it with grammar glasses.

Comment: This is the pithiest translation of the first part, and from my rudimentary understanding of French, it seems to be the closest.

Comment: Please explain your answer in full. Posing it as a question merely adds to the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Slogans with the same meaning might be:

> - **Here comes the free internet, good bye to (the) privacy**.
> - **If it's free, forget (the) privacy.**

Comment: Too specific, in my humble opinion.  The cost might be something other than your privacy; for example, it's often your time.

Comment: In both cases, "the privacy" should, I think, be "privacy".

Comment: "If it's free, say goodbye to your privacy" has a good rhyme to it :)

Answer (score 1):

Free? Then you're paying with your freedom.

Comment: You need to present your views. Such hort answers are not professional and expected.

Answer (score 1):

"If you don't know who is the mark, you are the mark."

(Context: "mark" here in the sense of a target to be fleeced, e.g., in a crooked gambling game.)

Answer (score 0):

At first I thought, **The first hit's always free.** But that speaks more to making money off you, rather than you becoming the thing bought and sold -- you know, like those contests for free cars that are thinly disguised ploys to get your marketing information.

I think **if it's free, you're the product** is good enough, unless you're looking for the equivalent idiom in English.